# Overwrite Django Rest Framework header for OPTION requests

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

When I send a http OPTION request to an endpoint, Django rest Framework responds with the following paylod:

```
{
    "name": "Get Categorias",
    "description": "",
    "renders": [
        "application/json",
        "text/html"
    ],
    "parses": [
        "application/json",
        "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "multipart/form-data"
    ]
}
```

And The Following headers:

```
Date →Fri, 08 Feb 2019 12:25:50 GMT
Server →Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
Content-Length →173
Vary →Accept
Allow →GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
X-Frame-Options →SAMEORIGIN
Keep-Alive →timeout=5, max=100
Connection →Keep-Alive
Content-Type →application/json
```

Here's the code:

```
@permission_classes((AllowAny,))
class GetCategorias(APIView):
    def get(self, request):

        query = "SELECT * FROM categoria ORDER BY nome ASC;"

        find = FuncaoCursorFetchAll.queryCursor(query)
        if find:
            result = []
            for cat in find:
                result.append({"id" : cat[0], "categoria" : cat[1]})


            response = JsonResponse({"categorias" : result}, encoder=DjangoJSONEncoder,safe=False,content_type="application/json;charset=utf-8")
            response['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
            response['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'GET, OPTIONS, HEAD'
            response['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Content-Type, Authorization'
            return response
        else:
            data = {"error": "Nenhum registro encontrado"}
```

Url definition:

```
path('categorias/', views.GetCategorias.as_view(), name='categorias'),
```

I need to overwrite this headers. I don't Know from where this is coming since I don't have an explicit endpoint for OPTIONS request. Anyone can help me to discover where I can configure the correct headers I need?

Comment: Please add your URL definitions and the corresponding ViewSets to have a more complete understanding of the problem.

Comment: I edited the question with the code.

Answer (score 5):

You can override `options` easily.

```
from rest_framework.response import Response

class ClassBasedView(APIView):
    def options(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return Response({'foo': 'bar'})

@api_view(['GET', 'POST', 'OPTIONS'])
def func_based_view(request):
    if request.method == 'OPTIONS':
        return Response({'foo': 'bar'})
    else:
        return Response({'message': 'not options!'})
```

If you don't know about view in REST framework? Check [this doc](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/)

And you want to override headers? You can give your own header by `Response`. Check this [Response doc](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/responses/)

Your `OPTIONS` payload is `metadata` of your view. You can also override metadata. See this [Metadata doc](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/metadata/)